Meaning of product of odds $O_1 O_2$ (and its geometric mean)
Consider I have two independent events $E_1$ and $E_2$, with associated probabilities $p_1$ and $p_2$. The odds of $E_1$ is $O_1 = \frac{p_1}{1-p_1}$ and the odds of $E_2$ is similar. In the problem I am facing, the geometric mean of these odds, $G=\sqrt{O_1 O_2}$ emerges from the math.
The product of the Odds seem to be related to the ratio between the probability of both events happening and the probability of neither event happening:
$$
O_1 O_2 = \frac{p_1 p_2 }{(1-p_1)(1-p_2)} = \frac{\Pr(E_1 \land E_2)}{\Pr(\lnot E_1 \land \lnot E_2)}
$$
But I could not relate this to anything useful, I don't know any instances where this ratio could make sense or could be ascribed some meaning. Further, the problem is not only $O_1 O_2$, but its geometric mean. Maybe is the odds of an event $E_3$ whose ratio between chance of success twice and chance of failure twice is equivalent to $O_1 O_2$?
Have you seen anything like this that I could look to establish some parallels?

Suppose you are playing a sport such as tennis, and a player wins a set if they are $2$ games ahead of their opponent and loses if they are $2$ games behind (no need to get to $6$ in this version, and no tie-breaks), with serve alternating between games.
If for a given player the probability of winning a service game is $p_1$ and winning a non-service game is $p_2$,  the corresponding odds of that player winning a service game are $O_1$ and of winning a non-service game are $O_2$.
The odds of that player winning a set are then $O_1 O_2$.
This corresponds to a probability of that player winning a set of $\frac{p_1 p_2}{p_1 p_2 +(1-p_1)(1-p_2)}$.

The geometric mean $O_{gm}=\sqrt{O_1 O_2}$ are the odds which, if the service game and non-service game odds were equal, would give the same odds of winning the set as the original unequal pair of game odds.

I am somewhat confused. Assuming the two services are independent, I would assume that the probability of winning both services in a set is the probability of winning the serving times the probability of winning a non-serving one: i.e. $p_1 p_2$. Also, the Odds of A and B is $O_{AB} = O_A * O_B / (1 + O_A + O_B) = p_1p_2/ (1 - p_1p_2)$, so I didn't understand your statement about the odds of that player winning being $O_1 O_2$, would that apply to the sequential character of the games?

on this, I think that the probability of the player winning a set might not be correct because if you assume that $p_1=1$ , then the probability of the player winning the set is also equal to 1, irrespective of the value of $p_2$

@RMS On your second comment, if $p_1=1$ and $p_2 >0$ then $O_1=\infty$ and $O_2>0$ so $O_1O_2 =\infty$ and thus my answer says the probability of the player winning the set is equal to $1$.  If $p_1=1$ and $p_2 =0$ then the set never finishes.

@RMS Otherwise (so your first comment) the set continues if the player wins a game and then loses a game (or the reverse) so the probability of the player winning a set is higher than $p_1p_2$  and is  $p_1p_2 + (p_1(1-p_2)+(1-p_1)p_2)p_1p_2 +  (p_1(1-p_2)+(1-p_1)p_2)^2p_1p_2 + \cdots$ $=\frac{p_1p_2}{1- (p_1(1-p_2)+(1-p_1)p_2)}$ $=\frac{p_1p_2}{p_1p_2 +(1-p_1)(1-p_2)}$. The corresponding odds are $\frac{\frac{p_1p_2}{p_1p_2 +(1-p_1)(1-p_2)}}{1-\frac{p_1p_2}{p_1p_2 +(1-p_1)(1-p_2)}}$ $=\frac{p_1p_2}{(1-p_1)(1-p_2)} = O_1O_2$.

It would take me 4 years to think about that! Thanks.I think my main confusion was that I did not consider the sequence of all the games, but just the first two.
